# How to save skeleton of an image as svg?

Tags: python, opencv, svg, image-processing

I have obtained the skeleton of an image. Like this

```
im = imread('testimage.png',as_gray=True)

t = threshold_otsu(im)

r = skeletonize(im>threshold_otsu(im))*255
```

**Code copied from SO*

Now I want the skeleton as an svg file.

I think I can try plotting it using pyplot and then use the savefig() method. But I am a beginner. Does someone has a good way of going about this?

Comment: [Skeleton Tracing](https://github.com/LingDong-/skeleton-tracing) might be the right library for your needs, since it can output skeletons as svg paths.

Comment: Just searching Google, I find: https://github.com/FHPythonUtils/SvgTrace and https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/

Comment: Note that the skeleton is an image, not a set of lines. You can find lines in it, but it’s not a trivial operation.